# Getting info about inheritance chain in Crystal

Tags: ruby, inheritance, reflection, metaprogramming, crystal-lang

Just out of curiosity and to learn a little bit about the general structure of Crystal, I was looking for some reflection features that would allow me to better understand how the inheritance chain is built.

I was thinking something like ruby's [superclass](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Class.html#method-i-superclass), [ancestors](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-ancestors) or [included_modules](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Module.html#method-i-included_modules) methods.

Is there something like that available in Crystal language?

Moreover, it would be useful to have some kind of diagram that could show me the big picture.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Metaprogramming in Crystal is achieved using [macros](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/macros.html).

> Macros are methods that receive AST nodes at compile-time and produce code that is pasted into a program.

Crystal already has implementations of [`superclass`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.23.1/Crystal/Macros/TypeNode.html#superclass%3ATypeNode%7CNilLiteral-instance-method) and [`ancestors`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.23.1/Crystal/Macros/TypeNode.html#ancestors%3ACrystal%3A%3AMacros%3A%3AArrayLiteral%28TypeNode%29-instance-method) which return results at compile time. So you can do:

```
{{ pp MyClass.superclass }}
{{ pp MyClass.ancestors }}
```

For convenience, to inspect the inheritance you can write your own macros. Having learning purpose in mind, it may look like this:

```
class Class
  def superclass
    {{ @type.superclass }}
  end

  def ancestors
    {% if @type.ancestors.size > 0 %}
      {{ @type.ancestors }}
    {% else %}
      [] of Nil
    {% end %}
  end

  def included_modules
    {% if @type.ancestors.any? { |a| a.class.stringify.ends_with?(":Module") } %}
      {{ @type.ancestors.select { |a| a.class.stringify.ends_with?(":Module") } }}
    {% else %}
      [] of Nil
    {% end %}
  end

  def inheritance_chain
    String.build do |chain|
      cls = self
      chain << cls
      while !(cls = cls.superclass).nil?
        chain << " > #{cls}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can do the inspection:

```
class A
end

module B
end

require "crystal/system/random"

class C < A
  include B
  include Crystal::System::Random
end

C.name             # => "C"
C.superclass       # => A
C.ancestors        # => [Crystal::System::Random, B, A, Reference, Object]
C.included_modules # => [Crystal::System::Random, B]
A.included_modules # => []
```

And if you go further:

```
C.superclass                                                    # => A
C.superclass.try &.superclass                                   # => Reference
C.superclass.try &.superclass.try &.superclass                  # => Object
C.superclass.try &.superclass.try &.superclass.try &.superclass # => nil
```

And now using `inheritance_chain`:

```
Int32.inheritance_chain                          # => "Int32 > Int > Number > Value > Object"
String.inheritance_chain                         # => "String > Reference > Object"
Float64.inheritance_chain                        # => "Float64 > Float > Number > Value > Object"
Array(Bool).inheritance_chain                    # => "Array(Bool) > Reference > Object"
Hash(Bool, Bool).inheritance_chain               # => "Hash(Bool, Bool) > Reference > Object"
Tuple(Char).inheritance_chain                    # => "Tuple(Char) > Struct > Value > Object"
NamedTuple(s: String, b: Bool).inheritance_chain # => "NamedTuple(s: String, b: Bool) > Struct > Value > Object"
Nil.inheritance_chain                            # => "Nil > Value > Object"
Regex.inheritance_chain                          # => "Regex > Reference > Object"
Symbol.inheritance_chain                         # => "Symbol > Value > Object"
Proc(Int32).inheritance_chain                    # => "Proc(Int32) > Struct > Value > Object"
Set(String).inheritance_chain                    # => "Set(String) > Struct > Value > Object"
Exception.inheritance_chain                      # => "Exception > Reference > Object"
Class.inheritance_chain                          # => "Class > Value > Object"

# union
alias UnionType = Int32 | Nil | String
UnionType.inheritance_chain                      # => "(Int32 | String | Nil) > Value > Object"

# nilable
Int32?.inheritance_chain                         # => "(Int32 | Nil) > Value > Object"

# pointer
alias Int32Ptr = Int32*
Int32Ptr.inheritance_chain                       # => "Pointer(Int32) > Struct > Value > Object"

# ...
```

Comment: Great answer! BTW, is it possible to have a look at the source of these methods? (tried here https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/e2a1389e8165fb097c785524337d7bb7b550a086/src/compiler/crystal/macros.cr#L1508, but they are just there for documentation purposes)

Comment: Use `{{ pp MyClass.superclass }}` instead of `pp({{ MyClass.superclass }})`, in order to avoid "Invalid memory access (signal 11)" in crystal 0.34+

Comment: @Vitali Great answer indeed! If it isn't too much to ask, can you also please add some information on how to fetch methods in the inheritance chain (I'm particularly stumped at fetching them in the reverse order, most derived class first).